# Is italic formatting broken on mobile?

Tags: support, bug

Pixel 4a, Android 12,Chrome 96.0.4664.45

For the last few weeks noticed that *italics* whether using single star or *underscore* or *selecting text* to format from formatting bar does not render.

[image]

Works with laptop (  Chrome 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit))
as it should. Maybe SE depreciating Android version is the reason
*Just wanted to confirm* (this is in italics because it is on laptop)

Edit: Switched to mobile and realized that italics don't render on mobile display but do on laptop. So, italicize on mobile but don't expect to see it, unless this issue is fixed, which is unlikely.

Comment: Somehow I couldn't repro it on Pixel 3a, Android 12, latest stable Chrome (96.0.4664.45). Both mobile and full site displayed italic properly. Strange...

Comment: @AndrewT indeed very strange. No mod interfering with Chrome 